# IIS won't forward the logged on user credential to webservice request?

Tags: authentication, iis

Ive  enabled `Windows authentication` in my IIS.

*for the sample* lets assume my Active directory username  is **\domain\John**

[image]

**My task flow is like that :**

Iis won't forward the loged on user credential to webservice request?

[image]

the Page1.aspx `request` some data from a WebService ( also in my iis ).

However , it does NOT  pass the **\domain\John** Information . (through the request).

Other things are working well. ( I can touch a file with special permission via the impersonation)

But when the asp.net calls the webservice  - it fails ( 401 - not autorized).

**p.s.**

If i set `...useDefaultCredentials = true` ( in my c# code) - its working.

I want the IIS to "forward the **\domain\John**"  with the request of the webservice.

**How can I do that ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a better question for Serverfault.

What you need to do for this to be workable is to configure Constrained Delegation. With a regular NTLM logon, your credentials aren't forwardable to another service.

With a Basic (you may need to change the LogonType value to allow it) logon, you could do this because the target server has your credentials; with NTLM, it's not able to make the second hop.